# Highlight all words in jTextField that the user puts into search for

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

Hey all the following code below works with highlighting the supplied word to search for but if there are more than just one (1) of that word in the sentence then it wont find it. It just stops at finding one (1) match.

```
private JFrame frame;
private static JTextField textField;
private static JTextField txtWorld;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CaretDemo window = new CaretDemo();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);

                String text = "hello world. How are you?";

                textField.setText(text);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public CaretDemo() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(21, 11, 350, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    txtWorld = new JTextField();
    txtWorld.setColumns(10);
    txtWorld.setBounds(21, 156, 350, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtWorld);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Highlighter highlighter = textField.getHighlighter();
            HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);          
            int p0 = textField.getText().indexOf(txtWorld.getText());
            int p1 = p0 + txtWorld.getText().length();

            try {
                highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
                highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btnNewButton.setBounds(221, 203, 128, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}
```

The above code looks like this when ran and supplied the word "world" to find.

[image]

But now if I add to the sentence and add another "world" then hit the button this is what it looks like:

[image]

As you see, it still has the same highlighted word without also highlighting the second (2) "world".

**UPDATE 1**

I have attempted using regex in order to loop and find the needed word.

```
btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        String theSentence = txtTheSentence.getText();
        String WordToFind = txtWordToFind.getText();
        Highlighter h = txtWordToFind.getHighlighter();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+WordToFind+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theSentence);

        if(matcher.find()){
            String extractedWord = matcher.group(0);
            System.out.println(extractedWord);
        }
    }
});
```

But this does not produce even one word found.

Comment: Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/728672/java/Highlight-words-jTextField-user-puts. The same advice was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally!

```
btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        String theSentence = txtTheSentence.getText();
        String theWord = txtWordToFind.getText();
        Highlighter h = txtWordToFind.getHighlighter();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(theWord, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theSentence);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String extractedWord = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(extractedWord);
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It does not do any highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

> it still has the same highlighted word without also highlighting the second (2) "world" -

Well that is exactly what your code does.

First you remove all the highlights and then add back a single highlight.

If you want multiple words to be highlighted then you need to:

1. first remove all the highlights and then
2. write a loop and process all the text in the string.

You can use the `String.indexOf(text, fromIndex)` method to continue the search from a new index once you find the matching text.

Comment: I still don't see a loop anywhere. I can't help you with a regex, since I don't know how to use them. You know how to use the indexOf(…) method. You just need to make a loop.

Comment: Glad the suggestion pointed you in the right direction. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.